# Use the result of enrichKEGG() to make the dotplot

Tags: r

```
entrezid_downgene=structure(list(SYMBOL = c("ARHGEF16", "ILDR1", "TMPRSS4", "MAP7", "SERINC2", "C9orf152", "TSPAN1", "RHEX", "TMC4", "CRB3", "UGT8", "CD24", "MAPK13", "AGR2", "GJB1", "ERBB3", "CNDP2", "LOC105378644", "GCNT3", "CEACAM1", "GPR160", "PRSS8", "HOOK1", "ABHD17C", "MOCOS", "CWH43", "EHF", "ACSL5", "SLC44A4", "RAP1GAP", "MUC13", "PPM1H", "ATP2C2", "RAB25", "H2BC5", "H4C12", "TJP3", "RXFP1", "GSTO2", "OVOL2", "TMEM125", "LIMS1", "DLX5", "ST6GALNAC1", "HNF1B", "STX19", "F2RL1", "MT1G", "PLPP2", "TMEM238", "SLC30A2", "GABRP", "EPCAM", "CLDN10", "HOXB5", "PRAME", "MAL2", "PLA2G10", "TSPAN12", "FAM174B", "TMC5", "ASRGL1", "SCNN1A", "FOXL2", "ALDH3B2", "ELF3", "SLC7A1", "MT1F", "CLDN3", "SPINT2", "SFN", "VWC2", "C9orf116", "SLC39A6", "TCN1", "IL20RA", "ACSM3", "FOXL2NB", "HGD", "PAX8", "IDO1", "C4BPA", "RHPN2", "HMGCR", "UGT2B11", "PIGR", "MUC20", "SLC3A1", "PLLP", "PSAT1", "SCGB2A1", "WNT5A", "DEFB1", "FGL1", "SLC2A8", "HOXB8", "CYP2J2", "WWC1", "MUC1", "PRKX", "RASEF", "BAIAP2L2", "PAPSS1", "MME", "HOMER2", "STRA6", "ARG2", "MOGAT1", "CDS1", "SCGB2A2", "MPZL2", "PHYHIPL", "INAVA", "IDO2", "GALNT4", "TMEM101", "HSD17B2", "AOC1", "CDCA7", "CAPS", "TFCP2L1", "PAEP", "PLAC9P1", "GAL", "RORB", "CCNO", "XDH", "C15orf48", "SLC1A1", "GPT2", "VNN1", "NWD1", "HABP2", "UGT2B7", "CYP26A1", "MSX1", "ENPP3", "KIR2DL3", "ADAMTS9", "KIR2DL4", "BRINP1", "PROM1", "APCDD1", "AGR3", "EYA2", "SLC2A1", "GNLY", "COL7A1", "FOXJ1", "MS4A8", "C20orf85", "RSPH1", "SCGB1D2", "SPP1", "RASD1", "CST1", "SCGB1D4", "LEFTY1", "LAMC3", "TEKT1", "LCN2", "VTCN1", "IRX3", "ROPN1L", "FAM183A", "NDP", "TUBB3", "DIO2", "IL2RB", "ADAMTS8", "SERPINA5", "NKG7", "ABCC8", "STC1", "LRRC26"), 
               ENTREZID = c("27237", "286676", "56649", "9053", "347735", "401546", "10103", "440712", "147798", "92359", "7368", "100133941", "5603", "10551", "2705", "2065", "55748", "105378644", "9245", "634", "26996", "5652", "51361", "58489", "55034", "80157", "26298", "51703", "80736", "5909", "56667", "57460", "9914", "57111", "3017", "8362", "27134", "59350", "119391", "58495", "128218", "3987", "1749", "55808", "6928", "415117", "2150", "4495", "8612", "388564", "7780", "2568", "4072", "9071", "3215", "23532", "114569", "8399", "23554", "400451", "79838", "80150", "6337", "668", "222", "1999", "6541", "4494", "1365", "10653", "2810", "375567", "138162", "25800", "6947", "53832", "6296", "401089", "3081", "7849", "3620", "722", "85415", "3156", "10720", "5284", "200958", "6519", "51090", "29968", "4246", "7474", "1672", "2267", "29988", "3218", "1573", "23286", "4582", "5613", "158158", "80115", "9061", "4311", "9455", "64220", "384", "116255", "1040", "4250", "10205", "84457", "55765", "169355", "8693", "84336", "3294", "26", "83879", "828", "29842", "5047", "389033", "51083", "6096", "10309", "7498", "84419", "6505", "84706", "8876", "284434", "3026", "7364", "1592", "4487", "5169", "3804", "56999", "3805", "1620", "8842", "147495", "155465", "2139", "6513", "10578", "1294", "2302", "83661", "128602", "89765", "10647", "6696", "51655", "1469", "404552", "10637", "10319", "83659", "3934", "79679", "79191", "83853", "440585", "4693", "10381", "1734", "3560", "11095", "5104", "4818", "6833", "6781", "389816")),
          row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L), class = "data.frame") 
          

down_ekk <- enrichKEGG(gene= c(entrezid_downgene$ENTREZID),
                  organism  = 'hsa', 
                  pvalueCutoff = 0.05,
                  minGSSize = 50,
                  maxGSSize = 500,
                  
)
dot <- dotplot(down_ekk,font.size=6,title='down_kegg')  
dot
```

> Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : Change the
> parameter length to zero Warning message: In rep(yes, length.out =
> len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

please How to solve the error?

Comment: Can you add an exemple of `entrezid_downgene` to your post ? We need to know what is the output of `dput(entrezid_downgene)`

Comment: Thanks for editing but what you add is unreadable  and what we would need is the output of `dput(entrezid_downgene)`, it is something that should begin with `structure(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal you can't plot the dotplot because you have no significant ontologies.
You can check with `down_ekk` :

```
downekk
#
# over-representation test
#
#...@organism    hsa 
#...@ontology    KEGG 
#...@keytype     kegg 
#...@gene    chr [1:175] "27237" "286676" "56649" "9053" "347735" "401546" "10103" "440712" "147798" "92359" "7368" "100133941" "5603" "10551" "2705" "2065" "55748" "105378644" "9245" "634" "26996" "5652" ...
#...pvalues adjusted by 'BH' with cutoff <0.05 
#...0 enriched terms found
#...Citation
  Guangchuang Yu, Li-Gen Wang, Yanyan Han and Qing-Yu He.
  clusterProfiler: an R package for comparing biological themes among
  gene clusters. OMICS: A Journal of Integrative Biology
  2012, 16(5):284-287
```

"0 enriched terms found" so this is why you get the error as no dotplot can be plotted

Comment: Thanks,so should I change the pvalue into 0.1 or 0.9?

Comment: It depends on when you consider a result is significant, and this is rather a question of statistics and bioinformatics which is not the topic of this forum